# return the nth element of a list in OCaml?

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

I am new to Ocaml, just want to make sure how to perform a simple function such as return the nth element of a list by using recursive function?

Prototype like `get_nth (list, n)`  with `int list * int -> int`

for example `get_nth ([1,2,3], 1) -> 2`

Thank you

Comment: This really sounds like a homework problem.  It would help if you showed some code that you've tried that doesn't work as you hoped.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may not notice but `List.nth` function is already there in [List module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html).

If you want to write it using recursion:

```
let rec get_nth = function
    | [], _ -> raise (Failure "get_nth")
    | _, n when n < 0 -> raise (Invalid_argument "get_nth")
    | x::_, 0 -> x
    | x::xs, n -> get_nth(xs, n-1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Using tuples as parameters like this is not common in OCaml. Usually you would use currying and define your function like this:

```
let get_nth list n = ...
```

This would have the signature `'a list -> int -> 'a`. Also note that you have a `'a` paramter here, which means, there is no real reason to restrict your function to ints alone.

Now let's look at the problem. If you want to get the zeroth element, what would your function look like?

```
let get_nth list 0 = List.head list (* this is not actually valid in OCaml *)
```

now if you have a function to get the nth element from a list of m items (N.B. n > m), how could you use that function to build another function which get's the n+1st element from a list of m+1 elements? Let that function for n+1 elements be `get_nth'`

```
let get_nth' list n' = get_nth (List.tail list) (n'-1)
```

Now all you need to do is to combine the two and you are done. I'll leave that last part up to you.

If you follow this advice you will get something which is more complicated, than it has to be. However it is easier to understand what is happening this way.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm afraid your attempt is more confusing than it needs to be. Ocaml pattern matching is quite visually explanative on its own.

Answer (score 3):

(In my opinion) A simpler solution without using a tuple can be:

```
let rec get_nth mylist index = match mylist with
    | [] -> raise (Failure "empty list")
    | first::rest -> 
        if index = 0 then first 
        else get_nth rest (index-1)
;;
```

Comment: I would have made this the correct answer. Using tuple as an argument in Ocaml function isn't very idiomatic and requires allocation.

Answer (score 0):

I've read [here](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/error-handling.html) that using `Result` instead of raising error can be nicer  since you don't have to use a `try ... with`. (Code edited from @Omar)

```
let rec get_nth mylist index = match mylist with
    | [] -> Error "empty list"
    | first::rest -> 
        if index = 0 then Ok first 
        else get_nth rest (index-1)
;;

let result [1; 2; 3] 2 in 
    match result with
    | Error reason -> print_string reason
    | Ok num -> print_int num
;;
```

`Result` is part of `Core.Std`, if I'm correct.